# Get stack trace inside unhandledrejection event handler

Tags: javascript, promise, stack-trace

How can I determine where the Promise rejection happened when I only caught it using `onunhandledrejection` handler?

```js
console.error = ()=>{}
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (promiseRejectionEvent) => {
  console.log('unhandled: ', Error().stack)
})

function main() {
  new Promise(() => { throw null })
}
main()
```

If you check your browser's console after running this, you will see something like:

[image: sources tab]
[image: console output]

The `Error().stack` only includes the rejection handler function itself in its stack trace (grey output `js:14:30`). But the browser *does* seem to know where the rejection happened: There is another red error output (`Uncaught (in promise) null`), pointing to the target line (`js:18`). How can I access this line information?

It seems that the latter output is being done by the browser's internals, as it is not preventable by overwriting `console.error` like in the example above. It is only preventable by calling `promiseRejectionEvent.preventDefault()`, as explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event#Preventing_default_handling). But I don't want to prevent it anyway, but retrieve it instead, for example for logging purposes.

Real world use case: It would of course be possible to not rely on `onunhandledrejection` event handler, e.g. by adding a `.catch()` phrase or at least throwing `throw new Error(null)`. But in my case, I have no control over it as it is third party code. It threw unexpectedly today (probably a library bug) at a client's browser and the automatic error report did not include a stack trace. I tried to narrow down the underlying issue above. Thanks!

---

Edit in response to comments:

> Wrap the third party code in a try/catch? – weltschmerz

Good point, but this does not help because the rejection actually happens inside a callback:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (promiseRejectionEvent) => {
  console.log('unhandled: ', Error().stack) // <- stack once again does *not* include "main()", it is only printed out in the console
})

function main() {
  try {
    thirdPartyModule()
  } catch(e) {
    // Never caught
    console.log("caught:", e)
  }
}

// Example code
// We cannot change this function
function thirdPartyModule() {
  setTimeout(() =>
    new Promise(() =>
      { throw null }))
}

main()
```

Comment: Wrap the third party code in a try/catch?

Comment: @weltschmerz Yes, but the third party code does not actually return a Promise, so it cant be caught. I updated the answer with an example. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Using this workaround is useful for debugging, but has minor negative performance implications, and could cause various libraries to misbehave; it should not be used in production code.

---

You can replace the Promise constructor with your own implementation that includes a stack trace for where it was created.

```js
window.Promise = class FAKEPROMISE extends Promise {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.__creationPoint = new Error().stack;
    }
};
```

This will give you a stack trace of the point where any given promise was created.
Note that `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` all create new promises.

This will not function with Promises created by `async` functions, as those do not use the window's `Promise` constructor.

This can be used by reading the `promise` member of the `PromiseRejectionEvent`:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (promiseRejectionEvent) => {
  console.log('unhandled: ', promiseRejectionEvent.promise.__creationPoint)
})
```

Which will print something like:

```
unhandled:  Error
    at new FAKEPROMISE (script.js:4:32)
    at main (script.js:6:3)
    at script.js:9:1
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much! Funnily enough, now the browser-console-only `Uncaught (in promise) null` has a useless error line (points to the constructor), but the creationPoint logic has it. Seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity I ran some performance testing. The subclass constructor is ~100x slower than the vanilla `Promise` constructor. Some marginal improvement can be made by just storing the `Error` object and only accessing `error.stack` when needed (calculating the stack is also expensive), but doesn't save much compared to the overall performance hit: https://jsbench.me/qclp2w1c5k/1

Answer (score 2):

**It is not possible.**

I imagine the "stack trace" you want would include the line with `throw null;`, however, *that's not in the stack* when the `unhandledrejection` event handler is called. When `throw null;` is executed, the handler is not called directly (synchronously), but instead a microtask that calls the handler is queued. (For an explanation of the event loop, tasks and microtasks, see ["In The Loop" by Jake Archibald](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0).)

This can be tested by queuing a microtask right before throwing the error. If throwing calls the handler synchronously, the microtask should execute after it, but if throwing queues a microtask that calls the handler, the first microtask executes first, and then the second one (that calls the handler).

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (promiseRejectionEvent) => {
  console.log('unhandled: ', Error().stack) // <- stack once again does *not* include "main()", it is only printed out in the console
})

function main() {
  try {
    thirdPartyModule()
  } catch (e) {
    // Never caught
    console.log("caught:", e)
  }
}

// Example code
// We cannot change this function
function thirdPartyModule() {
  setTimeout(() =>
    new Promise(() => {
      Promise.resolve().then(() => { // Queue a microtask before throwing
        console.log("Microtask")
      })
      throw null
    }))
}

main()
```

As you can see, our microtask executed first, so that means the handler is called inside a microtask. The handler is at the top of the stack.

Comment: It makes sense what you are saying, but I dont think it is impossible: Check your browser console (not the one from SO) after executing  your code sample, and expand the red "Uncaught (in promise) null" message. You will see a nice stack trace pointing up to the `new Promise(() => {` line, but I cannot seem to get this information programmatically somehow. It's only in the console.

Comment: "I imagine the "stack trace" you want would include the line with `throw null;`" – well no, I actually meant (at least) the one with `main()` in it. Sorry if that wasnt clear enough. But it does not really matter much anyway, at least *some* useful stack trace lines would be great. In all current examples, the `unhandledrejection` event handler is plain useless.

Comment: That's also not possible, unfortunately. You can only get a stack trace up to the handler. I wouldn't say the `unhandledrejection` event is useless. All promise errors should be `.catch`ed, just like synchronous errors. The `unhandledrejection` event actually should never fire.

Answer (score 2):

There is no any good solution to track async stack trace out of the box, but it's possible to do using [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/zone.js). If you check out the demo on Zone.js page, there is example of an async stack trace.

Zone works by monkey patching all native API's that create async tasks to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.log('stackTrace:', reason.stack);
});
```

"reason" is a native Error object.
You can display the stackTrace with the "stack" property.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`.  Please do not confuse NodeJS with Browsers.  Not downvoting, though, because it might help others who share the same confusion ;)