# Get location information for PromiseRejectionEvent

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I have some code where `async` functions may throw errors and I'm dealing with them using `unhandledrejection` event, since those uncaught `throw` are not firing `error` events because they are happening inside a `Promise`. So, my error handler is getting `PromiseRejectionEvent` rather than `ErrorEvent`.

So far, so good, the error handling works as it should.

*BUT* I have a minor issue here, and it is that `PromiseRejectionEvent` events lack location information, unlike `ErrorEvent` events, and it would be very useful to have the location into the code where the error was thrown.

When the code was not using `async` functions, and the handler was getting `ErrorEvent` events, it was a matter of using `event.filename`, `event.lineno` and `event.colno`, but those are missing from `PromiseRejectionEvent` events.

**SO** my question is: can I wrap in any manner the `PromiseRejectionEvent` and re-dispatch it so in the end I have an `ErrorEvent` with location information?

I've tried something like this:

```
bigFunctionWithAllTheCodeIncludingAsyncFunctions()
.catch(error => {
    const errorEvent = new ErrorEvent('unhandledrejection', {
            'error': error,
    });
    window.dispatchEvent(errorEvent);
});
```

The above code generates a proper `ErrorEvent` with the relevant error information **BUT** all the location information is useless (`0` for line and column, '' for filename).

BTW, I already checked [Get stack trace inside unhandledrejection event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765986/get-stack-trace-inside-unhandledrejection-event-handler) but I cannot wrap promises in my code with a custom class, for now.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75722673/1048572) should actually work. Or `event.reason.stack` if you're in the browser - assuming, of course, that you actually reject your promises with `Error`s.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, in fact I'm already dumping the stack if at all possible, but that does not solve my problem, which is getting the error location properties. I can get that info from the stack if it exists, but it is non-standard, non-cross-browser and error prone because the format of the lines in the stack can change at any time. I prefer to have the location properties of `ErrorEvent`

Comment: You might prefer that, but it's not how it works. Btw, [`error.stack` is about to become standardised](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-error-stacks) as well.

Comment: @Bergi , thanks again for the information. I did not want to sound unrespectful O:) it's just that the code is for a small app I'm writing for a friend and I know for sure he won't be happy if I use things that are not already standardized. And thanks a LOT for the link, I did not know it was going to be standardized. It's time it gets! Thanks for your reply and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I wrap the `PromiseRejectionEvent` and re-dispatch it so in the end I have an `ErrorEvent` with location information?

Yes! But not by constructing and dispatching an `ErrorEvent` yourself. Instead, you'd use [`reportError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/reportError):

```js
window.onunhandledrejection = event => {
  reportError(event.reason);
};

window.onerror = (...args) => {
  console.log('onerror', args);
};

(async function() { throw new Error("oops"); }());
```

Comment: I owe you big time. Thanks A LOT for the answer, it works like a charm and I can't believe is SO SIMPLE. You solved my problem and in fact simplifed the code a lot for me. I didn't know about `reportError()`, there's so much JavaScript API I don't know that I feel stupid when the answer is so simple.

Comment: @Raúl I didn't know about it either :-) I looked in the spec for how standardised the `error` event was and just happened to come across it